# Separate log file for custom processor

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi 1.2.0

Need to create a separate log file, say, customprocessor.log besides the app.log file created by NiFi.

I went through some interesting, existing threads like this, however, I am unable to figure out how to make it working in the code.

Following is the existing logback.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <contextListener>
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>
    <appender name="APP_FILE">
        <file>/var/log/nifi/nifi-app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy>
            <!--
                               For daily rollover, use 'app_%d.log'.
              For hourly rollover, use 'app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log'.
              To GZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.gz'.
              To ZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.zip'.
            -->
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/nifi/archive/nifi-app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 log files worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
     <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    </appender>
    <appender name="USER_FILE">
        <file>/var/log/nifi/nifi-user.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy>
            <!--
                               For daily rollover, use 'user_%d.log'.
              For hourly rollover, use 'user_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log'.
              To GZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.gz'.
              To ZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.zip'.
            -->
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/nifi/archive/nifi-user_%d.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 log files worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="BOOTSTRAP_FILE">
        <file>/var/log/nifi/nifi-bootstrap.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy>
            <!--
              For daily rollover, use 'user_%d.log'.
              For hourly rollover, use 'user_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log'.
              To GZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.gz'.
              To ZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.zip'.
            -->
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/nifi/archive/nifi-bootstrap_%d.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 5 log files worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="CONSOLE">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <!-- valid logging levels: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR -->
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogAttribute" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteException" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.leader.LeaderSelector" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="org.apache.curator.ConnectionState" level="OFF" />
    <!-- Logger for managing logging statements for nifi clusters. -->
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.cluster" level="INFO"/>
    <!-- Logger for logging HTTP requests received by the web server. -->
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.server.JettyServer" level="INFO"/>
    <!-- Logger for managing logging statements for jetty -->
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="INFO"/>
    <!-- Suppress non-error messages due to excessive logging by class or library -->
    <logger name="com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com.sun.jersey.spi.spring" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
    <!-- Suppress non-error messages due to known warning about redundant path annotation (NIFI-574) -->
    <logger name="com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors" level="ERROR"/>
    <!--
        Logger for capturing user events. We do not want to propagate these
        log events to the root logger. These messages are only sent to the
        user-log appender.
    -->
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.web.security" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.web.api.config" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.authorization" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.cluster.authorization" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="USER_FILE"/>
    </logger>
    <!--
        Logger for capturing Bootstrap logs and NiFi's standard error and standard out.
    -->
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.bootstrap" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="BOOTSTRAP_FILE" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="BOOTSTRAP_FILE" />
    </logger>
    <!-- Everything written to NiFi's Standard Out will be logged with the logger org.apache.nifi.StdOut at INFO level -->
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.StdOut" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="BOOTSTRAP_FILE" />
    </logger>
    <!-- Everything written to NiFi's Standard Error will be logged with the logger org.apache.nifi.StdErr at ERROR level -->
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.StdErr" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="BOOTSTRAP_FILE" />
    </logger>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="APP_FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Now, I can add a new appender for the custom log file :

```
<!-- Start : Separate log file for custom processor -->
<appender name="CUSTOM_FILE">
        <file>/var/log/nifi/custom-processor.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy>
            <!--
                               For daily rollover, use 'app_%d.log'.
              For hourly rollover, use 'app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log'.
              To GZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.gz'.
              To ZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.zip'.
            -->
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/nifi/archive/custom-processor_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 log files worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
     <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    </appender>
<!-- End : Separate log file for custom processor -->



<!-- Start : Separate log file for custom processor -->
    <logger name="com.nifi.CustomLog" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM_FILE" />
    </logger>
    <!-- End : Separate log file for custom processor -->
```

I have the following questions :

1. Are the entries that I am adding correct
2. In the code, I use the following snippet to get the root logger,
   however, I didn't find a method/constructor to get my custom logger
   in the code, how shall I do that ?

   import org.apache.nifi.logging.ComponentLog;..final ComponentLog logger = getLogger();logger.debug("...");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have custom processor with class name: `org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript`

To get logger i'm using `this.getLogger()`

In this case adding the following configuration to `conf/logback.xml` will create a separate file `logs/x.log` where only logs from my processor will appear.

```xml
<appender name="X_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/x.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/x_%d.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript" level="INFO" >
    <appender-ref ref="X_FILE"/>
</logger>
```

Note that in the logger definition there should be your processor's class name

You can also define the package name (or parent package name) as a logger name to cover several processors located in this package:

```xml
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx" level="INFO" >
    <appender-ref ref="X_FILE"/>
</logger>
```

in this case all classes of `org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx` package
and all sub-packages will be logged into `X_FILE` logger.

Comment: Works well. Maybe I am a bit confused but is there a way to avoid the classname in the logger, instead, allow the processor classes to 'lookup' this particular logger ? This will enable several processors to share the log file ...

Comment: i've added description for package

Comment: @daggett Hello! Can you please point me to where I can find the list of all processors class names? I coulnd't find it anywhere.

Comment: depends what you are looking for. sources here: https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/main/nifi-nar-bundles or there is an api on your server: http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/flow/processor-types